# Rx.Observable.bindCallback with scope in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

It seems in rxjs 4.x, Rx.Observable.fromCallback accept scope as the second parameter, but in 5.0, this method is changed to Rx.Observable.bindCallback and doesn't accept scope parameter. How to add scope parameter in bindCallback. For example in ES6.

```
class Test {
  constructor(input) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  callback(cb) {
    return cb(this.input);
  }

  rx() {
    // this works on rx 4.x
    // var observable = Rx.Observable.fromCallback(this.callback, this)();

    // this doesn't work, because this.callback function doesn't use original this, so cannot get this.input
    var observable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(this.callback)();

    // Work around: Rx.Observable.bindCallback(this.callback)();
    // var me = this;
    // var observable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback((cb) => {me.callback(cb);})();

    observable.subscribe(
      input => console.log('get data => ' + input),
      err => console.log('get error =>' + err),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
   }
  }

  new Test(100).rx();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, when I add this to the constructor

```
  constructor(input) {
    this.input = input;
    this.callback = this.callback.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: This is another work around. Actually you rewrite the original function `callback` via bind. In another word, if I have multiple functions to use in `bindCallback` I have to bind this to those functions in constructor.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback which shows how to do this.

> *Use bindCallback on object method*
>
> `const boundMethod = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(someObject.methodWithCallback);
>   boundMethod.call(someObject) // make sure methodWithCallback has access to someObject
>   .subscribe(subscriber);`

You can call it immediately without declaring a variable, and also pass args like this:

```
Rx.Observable.bindCallback(someObject.callback).call(someObject,<args>)
```

So  to bind to `this` you can simply call

```
Rx.Observable.bindCallback(this.callback).call(this,<args>)
```

Comment: Or `const mine = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(someObject.callback.bind(someObject)); mine.subscribe(console.info)`